# Data Import Wizard congratulations window not able to close it

Tags: import, data-import-wizard, data-import

[image]Logged in as a standard user and tried to insert the lead record using data import wizard.
I flowed all steps which were mentioned step by step but at the end, I am getting "congratulations your import has started" popup window I clicked "OK" but it will closing please refer the attached screenshot.

Comment: This seems highly likely to be an issue dependent on your local browser, browser extensions, network environment, etc., rather than solvable by Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

As what Satheesh has said, the problem that you're seeing might a browser issue. A more important question to ask is: **Did your lead records go into your org successfully?** That's what matters at the end of the day.